# tlf text field align right problem

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

i have a tlf text field created with action script.
when i add a

```
format.align = TextFormatAlign.RIGHT;
```

the area of tlftextfield that not have text not get selected, you have to click on the text to get foucs.

example link: http://aradon.co.il/test/tlf.html

here is the code:

```
   import fl.text.TLFTextField;
   import flash.text.TextFormat;
   import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;

   var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Tahoma", 13, 0x0);
   format.align = TextFormatAlign.RIGHT;

   var _valueField:TLFTextField = new TLFTextField();
   _valueField.width = 200;
   _valueField.height = 22;

   _valueField.x = 20;
   _valueField.y = 20;
   _valueField.wordWrap = true;
   _valueField.multiline = false;
   _valueField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
   _valueField.defaultTextFormat = format;

   _valueField.background = true;
   _valueField.backgroundColor = 0xc6c6c6;

   _valueField.setTextFormat( format );

   addChild(_valueField);


   _valueField.text = "text";
```

Comment: but what's your question? The example you provided seams to work as expected... maybe I'm missing something. EDIT: ok! I got it now, you cannot gain focus of the textfield when clicking on the background once you set the align to Right.

Comment: look here: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3893357/ this is my problem look at the answer also test it yourself the trick with the height and the font size

Comment: Just tested your code and it works fine for me: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1329053/editableTFAlignRight/test.html

Comment: your test missing when the filed height is 200 and the font -size 12 and what about tahoma font or arial?

Comment: hi yonathan, my test is your code compiled. And it seems to be different from the compiled example you provided.

Comment: i've uploaded another test with 200px height and Arial. Still works ok.  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1329053/editableTFAlignRight200/test.html

Comment: awasome!!! if can you try with multiline and post your code i wont to try it to?

Comment: This works like a  charm. Believe it or not but your code solved my text-alignment problem. Thank you very much!!!!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this same problem. My fix is posted over here:
https://github.com/alexdeefuse/TLFTextField-fix

I tested it only on single line TLFTextFields.

If you take a look at the fix, what I'm doing is go down the display list of the TLFTextField and correct the position of the SimpleButton inside there. (the button is responsible for the user input and TLF's extend DisplayObjectContainers).

Answer (score 0):

a workaround for your problem is to define a border for the textinput:

```
_valueField.border = true;
_valueField.borderColor = 0xc6c6c6;
```

This looks a bit buggy behavior with the tlf, when testing in flash ide (adding the textfield with the text tool) I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: i also tried witout the border and it give the same result when you set the align to right you cant click in the textarea area only on the text also check this post on adobe it describe more details about this issue http://forums.adobe.com/message/3893357/